# Android imageview be larger on small device screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having a problem with the  `imageView`

it's larger when i open it on small screen device

this image show the different 
[image]

on the left screen size its `1440 * 2560` 
and the right one its size  `400 * 800`

also this is my code xml `ImageView`

```
 <RelativeLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/tt">

<customfonts.RoundedImageView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:src="@drawable/ssz2"
 android:scaleType="fitXY"
 android:adjustViewBounds="false" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

and this is the class that's make my image rounded

```
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {

public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

    if (drawable == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    Bitmap b = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP
            && drawable instanceof VectorDrawable) {
        ((VectorDrawable) drawable).draw(canvas);
        b = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas();
        c.setBitmap(b);
        drawable.draw(c);
    }
    else {
        b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();

    Bitmap roundBitmap =  getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
    canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0,0, null);
}

public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
    Bitmap sbmp;
    if(bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius)
        sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, radius, radius, false);
    else
        sbmp = bmp;
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(sbmp.getWidth(),
            sbmp.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xffa19774;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight());

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
    canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.7f, sbmp.getHeight() / 2+0.7f,
            sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.1f, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);


    return output;
  }
}
```

and the imageView source size its `75 * 75`

i want to make the size if this imageView same in all device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing is that the image is the same size in pixels.
But as the density of the pixels is lower on the screen to the right it appears bigger.

What you need to do is to take the screen's pixels and density into account.

This is what Google is using dp for to make sure that the views look the same even if the screens are different between the devices.

There would be different ways of solving this, but I think you want to convert the size from pixels to dp before you draw it on the canvas.

Comment: any example or tutorial talk about this ?

Answer (score 0):

You use

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

If you want fixed size use

```
android:layout_width="75dp"
android:layout_height="75dp"
```

but I advice you not to.

Read more about density independence https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#density-independence

Comment: `px` its make my `ImageView` more smaller on large screen

Comment: My mistake. Use dp (also called dip as Density-independent Pixels)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your ImageView dimensions are set to be "wrap_content", and your content (image source) size is determined using pixels. On a device with a smaller screen where the are less pixels, those 75 pixels will look relatively larger.

You should set your ImageView to have a fixed dp size such as:

```
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
```

You could use a calculator such as this one: https://pixplicity.com/dp-px-converter/ to get the correct density-pixel dimensions.

Comment: same no thing changed same result on image

Answer (score 0):

To Support all screen devices you have to create multiple copies of with different dimensions.

```
res/drawable-mdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap for medium-density
res/drawable-hdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap for high-density
res/drawable-xhdpi/graphic.png        // bitmap for extra-high-density
res/drawable-xxhdpi/graphic.png       // bitmap for extra-extra-high-density
```

[**See Android official docs.**](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: i know about that's but i work for chat application so this image come from server